# Need file dialog for code running in Enthought Canopy

Tags: python, enthought, canopy

The common regular python file dialog from Tk crashes under Enthought Canopy.

What is the recommended way to get a file dialog for Canopy users?

The code below works fine for regular python:

```
import Tkinter, tkFileDialog

root = Tkinter.Tk()
root.withdraw()

file_path = tkFileDialog.askopenfilename()
```

Error msg when run under Canopy is:

```
2014-12-30 11:22:52.809 Python[51980:d0f] -[QNSApplication _setup:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x108657b70
```

Comment: The following might be relevant: https://support.enthought.com/entries/21793229-Using-Tkinter-Turtle-in-Canopy-s-IPython-panel

Comment: That explains why Tk could have problems.  Still, there must be an easy way to get a file dialog under Canopy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on what GUI backend you are using in your program. If your program also uses TK elsewhere, then follow the instructions in the link that Warren provided. If all you need is this dialog (and similar), Chuck's suggestion is probably easiest (especially since Qt is the default backend for IPython kernel that Canopy uses). I'm no Qt guru but I think you can simplify Chuck's suggestion to:

```
from PySide import QtGui
fname, _ = QtGui.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(None, 'Choose file','.')
```

See http://srinikom.github.io/pyside-docs/PySide/QtGui/QFileDialog.html

Answer (score 1):

For me, the easy alternative is to use Qt.

```
fname, _ = QtGui.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self.view, 'Open file','.')
```